# why delay() method not working in session storage?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a `class` after some time. but the delay method is not working in sessionStorage. I don't know why it's not working.

```
window.onload = function() {
  if (sessionStorage.getItem(".bts-popup") != 'true') {
    $('body.home, body.page-template-page-services').delay(10000).addClass('is-visible');
    sessionStorage.setItem('.bts-popup', 'true');
  }
}
```

Comment: Not working as it is not running? Or what? Not working can mean a lot of things. Is there an error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the JavaScript version of sleep()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep)

Comment: delay is for things that get queued up like animations. https://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: FYI: Hiding the `<body>` tag when the page firsts loads for 10 seconds would be subject to a Google SEO penalty.

Answer (score 5):

This has nothing to do with session storage, it is entirely due to the method you're calling after `delay`; `addClass` is not added to any queue.

The [docs](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) hint at this:

> The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases.

In your case simply use

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('body.home, body.page-template-page-services').addClass('is-visible');
},10000);
```

Comment: @Anandhan you're welcome, but my name isn't Alessio